# master_not_discovered_exception for Elasticsearch 5.5

Tags: elasticsearch

This is how my master's elasticsearch.yml looks like :

```
cluster.name: myelastic
node.name: myelastic-master1
node.master: true
node.data: false
indices.queries.cache.size: 20%
network.host: _ec2_
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["masterip1","masterip2","masterip3","dataip1","dataip2","dataip3","dataip4","dataip5"]
```

and this is how the elasticsearch.yml of the data node looks like:

```
cluster.name: myelastic
node.name: myelastic-data1
node.master: true
node.data: false
indices.queries.cache.size: 20%
network.host: _ec2_
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["masterip1","masterip2","masterip3","dataip1","dataip2","dataip3","dataip4","dataip5"]
```

When I try to do a curl -XGET 'myelastic-data1:9200/_cat/master?v&pretty'

```
{
   "error":{
      "root_cause":[
         {
            "type":"master_not_discovered_exception",
            "reason":null
         }
      ],
      "type":"master_not_discovered_exception",
      "reason":null
   },
   "status":503
}
```

Any idea if I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

set

network.host: *eth0*

and try to restart elasticsearch service